# Spring RedirectAttributes not working with @PostMapping(value = { "/", "/{id}" })

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-11

I have a Controller like this one:

```
@PostMapping(value = { "/" })
public String home(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
return "redirect:/index.html?xyz=abc";
}
```

It is redirecting the request to an Angular application and was working as expected.
But as soon as I changed the PostMapping annotation to:

```
@PostMapping(value = { "/", "/{id}" })
```

It started giving me a 405 error in chrome console as:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 ()
> https://My_IP/index.html?xyz=abc

Can anyone suggest what am I missing here?
Would it require a fix on the Java side or the Angular side?

Angular version: 8.1.3

RedirectAttributes are from org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the "/{id}" within the @postmapping the system tries to match the get redirect request to the /id itself, as it assumed "index.html" as id.
And as it was a get redirect, while the /id was a post request, it gave a 405 error.

I avoided the issue by not using the '/' directly, but adding an API name to it, such as below:

```
 @PostMapping(value = { "/home", "/home/{id}" })
```

after this, system did not try to match the https://My_IP/index.html?xyz=abc request to /home or /home/id.